# RichFaces, a4j:ajax rerender after valueChangeListener call

Tags: ajax, richfaces, rerender

Look my jsf, please: http://pastebin.com/yRLyZ9KJ or http://pastebin.com/hqYSU5eJ
The problem is: first rerender loginPage and then is called #{loginBean.onLanguageSelect}. Why?
PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I need to reRender AFTER a valueChangeListener. Example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{back.change}" 
onchange="submit()" value="#{item.value}" >
<f:selectItems value="#{back.ordemItems}"/>
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="parentPainel" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

valueChangeListener is not the way to go. I had the same issue solved it by using a onclick.
It would be :

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="language" binding="#{loginBean.languageEntry}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.languages}" />
    <a4j:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="loginPage" actionListener="#{loginBean.onLanguageSelect}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Actually it is the way to go. Why do I need call onLanguageSelect each click to the selectOneMenu? The issue is in JSF defect. It is wrong handling any ajax events where do you have nested forms.